# Need to sort and group tableviews using SQLite on iPhone

Tags: sqlite, uitableview, sorting

I have two different tableviews, one needs to be grouped by region, one needs to be listed alphabetically. I am using an SQLite database. The grouped tableview needs to be grouped by a column in the database called Region. The alphabetic view uses a column of data called hotSpgsName. Someone told me to use a NSDictionary, but I would like to know if I can access my SQLite directly. I am fairly new to programming, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to sort my `tableView`, so I wanted to add this answer in case anyone else is interested. In my `AppDelegate`, I have created a `NSMutableArray` where I open my `SQLite` database using a select statement:

```
const char *sqlStatement = "select * from horses";
```

All I did was add order by `horseName asc`

and my table view is now sorted in ascending order. Hope this helps someone else out there too.

Jaime

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it